# How to access NodeJS server that is running in the same pod?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy an app to Kubernetes. I have 2 containers: Angular app, hosted by nginx, and Node.js server. I run those containers in the same pod. The issue is that Angular app can't access the Node.js api.
Here is my nginx's default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```

Here is my Dockerfile for the Angular app:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build:prod

FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist/mag-ui /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Here is my deploy.yml that I run on a Kubernetes cluster:

```
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: mag
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: mag
  name: mag
  labels:
    app: mag
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mag
  minReadySeconds: 10
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mag
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: mag-api
        image: mag-api
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      - name: mag-ui
        image: mag-ui
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: mag
  name: mag-svc
  labels:
    app: mag
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: ui
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: mag
```

So when I deploy this to my local cluster (and forward port 8080:80 of service/mag-svc) and browse localhost:8080, the ui app tries to query data from Node.js server and fails with: `GET http://localhost:3000/api/mag/models net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

**However**, if I connect to Angular app container's shell and curl the `localhost:3000/api/mag/models`, it works fine and I get the expected response.

Looks like it tries to access localhost of my host vm, instead of localhost of a container where the Angular app is running. So, how to make the Angular app call Node.js api, that runs in the same pod?

Comment: Can try adding a [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for the `nodejs` [`Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) then update your [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) to proxy connections to the `Service` instead of `localhost` i.e. `proxy_pass http://mag-nodejs:3000`.

Comment: Thank you, this works, but it works a bit differently than I expected: it accesses the API through the nginx server, while I want to access it locally in the pod.

Comment: The traffic would be proxied through `kube-proxy` to your `mag-api` containers with the `Service` spec and updated `proxy_pass`. If you want to access the container using `localhost` it should work with your current config provided that the connections were from `localhost` (i.e. from inside the `Pod`, can `kubectl exec -it mag-ui -- curl http://localhost:3000/api/mag/models`). From your PC if you create the `Service` and forward traffic to it as well `kubectl port-forward mag-api 3000:3000` then connections from your PC to `localhost:3000` would be forwarded to the `Service`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`angular` runs in your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45307259/1423507) so the connections to `http://localhost:3000` from the app running in your browser are to your PC's `localhost:3000`.

You can create a [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for the `nodejs` container:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: mag
  name: mag-svc-api
  labels:
    app: mag
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    name: mag-api
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: mag
```

... then forward traffic for `localhost:3000` to the `Service`: `kubectl port-forward -n mag mag-svc-api 3000:3000`. Connections from the app running in your browser to `http://localhost:3000` would be forwarded to the `Service` -> container running in [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/).